Changing chart name in correlation to filters on dashboard
I'm currently using Apache Superset 4.0.0 on a project with multiple global filters on multiples dataset on a dashboard.
For good measure, i'm using jinja templating to get the most precise information in my viz. Sadly, the title of my charts can't take into account any change to the filters, for example : "Number of meetings", when we filter by day, "Number of meetings per day".
I tried using jinja templating in title but couldn't get it to work... Is there any way to make the chart title change depending on filter usage ?
Thank you
